# how to aggregate information on UIImage?

Tags: ios, quartz-2d

I want to draw on each drawing 1 more lines on my UIIMage, right now I do it by :

```
-(void)drawRect
{


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(myImage.size);


    code to draw line on current context...

    draw previous info from myImage:
    [myImage drawInRect:myRect];

    //store info from context back to myImage
    myImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    //append the image on the right side of current context:
    [myImage drawInRect:myRightRect];
}
```

problem is that I think that drawing entire image each time just for 1 more added line is very expensive, anyone has any idea how to optimize it?

Comment: Too less info to give you exact answer... Generally, drawRect overridings work slow, and this is "very expensive", yes. However, you  may get rid of such operations in some cases. If you need just to display one line on your view - add subview with this line. If you need some harder drawing - play with masks, alphas. If you exactly need this to be "image with line" (for example, for saving to file or uploading to server) - yes, you need to draw line on image like you do. P.S. Try to make your question more specific, give more details.

Comment: Is it for displaying on screen or not? Should the line be added EXACTLY in drawRect method?

Comment: I edited my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Nobody answered but here is the solution that I found:

1. first create bitmap context:

   ```
   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();


   CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate (NULL, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8,
                                                   0, colorSpace,(kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst));
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
   ```
2. draw lines and shapes into this context.
3. now to get back the info from context into bitamp image by using:

   ```
   CGImageRef leftScaleImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
   UIImage* leftScaleUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:leftScaleImage];
   ```

cheers!